# How to define an exported symbol's address

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, linker

Let's say I'm writing a C++ library which must export a variable, a data structure, called, for example, `ExpData`. So, programs linked against my libray can access this variable (there is a public header defining it as `extern void *ExpData[]`).

However, this data structure is internally the vtable of a C++ class. The class' name is, for example, `InternalType`. So, after looking at the generated assembly code, I found out that `InternalType`'s vtable is exported as `_ZTV12InternalType`.

Then, I need a way to make my library exported variable `ExpData` be resolved with the same address than `_ZTV12InternalType`, so that, when an external program reads my library's `ExpData` variable, it is actually reading `InternalType`'s vtable.

Just to clarify, `InternalType`'s vtable assembly code is:

```
    .type   _ZTV12InternalType,@object # @_ZTV12InternalType
    .section    .data.rel.ro._ZTV12InternalType,"aGw",@progbits,_ZTV12InternalType,comdat
    .weak   _ZTV12InternalType
    .align  16
_ZTV12InternalType:
    .quad   0
    .quad   _ZTI12InternalType
    .quad   _ZN12InternalType8vMethodXEi
    .size   _ZTV12InternalType, 24
```

So, I need a way to achieve this (or something else with the same effect):

```
    .type   ExpData,@object
    .globl  ExpData

    .type   _ZTV12InternalType,@object
    .section    .data.rel.ro._ZTV12InternalType,"aGw",@progbits,_ZTV12InternalType,comdat
    .weak   _ZTV12InternalType
    .align  16
_ZTV12InternalType:
ExpData:
    .quad   0
    .quad   _ZTI12InternalType
    .quad   _ZN12InternalType8vMethodXEi
    .size   _ZTV12InternalType, 24
```

Is it possible in the C++ side?

P.S.: I know I shouldn't rely on implementation-dependent details, like name mangling and C++ classes internal data, but just consider my library is going to run on very specific environments.

**EDIT**

I could solve my problem by passing `--defsym ExpData=_ZTV12InternalType` to the linker. However, I don't want to attach implementation details to external resources. Let's say I decide to map the class' vtable as a C structure called `InternalTypeVTable`. So, I could declare `ExpData` as `InternalTypeVTable ExpData;`. It would be great if I had to change only the source file, not the makefiles and linker scripts.

Comment: Don't you use a header for that?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yes, but the header is supposed to declare the variable, not define it. So, I need a way to define my variable as the entry point of a compiler generated structure.

Comment: So you want to do a crude form of reflection is what I'm seeing? Your question isn't entirely clear to me.

Comment: @ColeJohnson It's not exactly reflection. It could be any compiler generated data, not only a C++ class. If I have the symbol name of a compiler-generated structure, I need a way to associate a variable to it. I need to make them be resolved with the same address.

Comment: You should use an `ld` linker script to manually generate symbols at specific addresses.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Maybe a linker script is the only way. I just wanted to make sure there is no other way to do this, for example, inline asm code or something...

Comment: What you're proposing is definitely a total hack, so I think a linker script is the only way.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The problem with the linker script is that I didn't want my library users to be aware of those details. It would be great if my library could be linked against an application without requiring a custom linker script.

Comment: Could you please add an example showing how this variable/pointer to pointer is intended to be used.

Comment: I may be missing something (it would not be the first time), but is there anything preventing you from initializing it (assuming it is a pointer) in some kind of xxxLibraryInit() routine, and making it a use restriction saying that the init routine must be called before anything else from the library is used?

Comment: @HonkyTonk Your comment really makes sense and I noticed I was not explaining my problem so clearly. I made a small (but important) change in my question. `ExpData` is in fact an inline array of pointers, and not just a pointer to pointers.

Comment: @Sparky You really missed something, but it was not your fault. I made a small change in my question to make my problem clearer. `ExpData` is, in fact, a memory region, an array of pointers. As you said, if it were just a pointer, I could initialize it in an init routine (yes, I can use initialization routines in my library). But, `ExpData` is a whole memory region. So, I need  `ExpData` to be a kind of label to `_ZTV12InternalType`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC's `__attribute__ ((alias()))` does exactly why I need.

If I declare `ExpData` like :

```
void *ExpData[0] __attribute__ ((alias("_ZTV12InternalType")));
```

in my library's source file, I get the following assembly code:

```
    .globl  ExpData
ExpData = _ZTV12InternalType
```

So, the exported symbol `ExpData` references the same memory address than `_ZTV12InternalType`.

Comment: Yes but why `void**`? A vtable is not a pointer, it's more like an array.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, a vtable is, in fact, similar to an array. But, if I were to declare it as an array, I should define its length. Since I don't know its exact length, I decided to declare it as a pointer, so that I can access the vtable entries just like I would if it were an array (`ExpData[0]`, `ExpData[1]`, `ExpData[2]`, ...). So, it actually doesn't matter.

Comment: "I decided to declare it as a pointer, so that I can access the vtable entries just like I would if it were an array". You cannot. `ExpData` **resides at** the same address as the the first element of the vtable, which is initialized to 0. It does not **contain** the address of the first element of the vtable. It contains 0. So `ExpData[0]` would be a null pointer dereference. You can extract the vtable size from the assembly file. Do you see the three `quad` declarations? They are essentially the three pointers that constitute the vtable.

Comment: @n.m. You're absolutely right. I was not paying attention when I answered you. If I use `ExpData` as a pointer, trying to access any element would cause a segmentation fault, since the address stored in the pointer variable is NULL (as you said, the first element of the vtable is 0). So, the best way to declare `ExpData` is, indeed, `void *ExpData[]`. Actually, to define it, I don't even need to use the exact length. I could define it as `void *ExpData[0]`. This is enough to access it as if it were the startpoint of a memory region (not a pointer to a memory region). Thank you very much!

Comment: @n.m. And when I said I didn't know the array size, I meant it could change if the compiler decided to store data in other way (although even the vtable itself could go away if the compiler changed, since it's implementation detail...)

Comment: +1 Great suggestion that I totally overlooked. Looking forward to the OP verifying that this works.

Comment: You depend on the ABI anyway.If the ABI ever changes, your entire scheme may become invalid.